# How to take input from user on second popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to angular/Ionic. I need your help.

I have a date time picker through which user can select date and time. On clicking the `textbox` (from the page) i get `datetime` picker popup through which date & time can be selected. It was working fine till I was using it in separate page (page that is having the textbox on clicking which popup of date & time picker appears).

All was working fine till I have put this page (having textbox) as popup. This means now I have two popup.

1st for page and

2nd for date & time Picker.

Now on clicking the page popup I am able to get 2nd popup, but when I try to select date or time (from popup 2) nothing happens to popup 2 but all these events are triggering on popup 1.

what changes should i make so that these events can be trigger to correct popup (popup 2) ?

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: First of all, you should show us your code, so that we can see what you could have done wrong

Comment: Some code would be welcome and might be worth [reading this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and reformulate your question so it has chances of being answered.

Comment: snippet code of same :- https://codepen.io/harshitm/pen/ONOOpz 
here on first click current date and time is entered and on second click popup of date time appears